# JSON Local Storage not saving after the page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

Newbie here. I'm working on a project which has an array and lets a user to add new items to the array by typing them in a text box and then clicking a "Submit" button. I made it so the array would transform into JSON when I unloaded the page and back into JavaScript when I loaded it again. My script worked to save the items in local storage for a while. After some code refactoring the program suddenly stopped saving my items on the page refresh. I wanted to program it so that it would save it even if I turned off the computer.

I've tried searching online for a solution to my problem, but there doesn't seem to be anyone with a similar problem.

My code:

```
<body onload="Items" onunload="JSONItems">

    <textarea id="type" rows="2" cols="25"></textarea>

    <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var Items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Items"))
        var JSONItems = localStorage.setItem("Items", JSON.stringify(Items))

        if (!Items) Items= []

        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var newitem = $("#type").val()
            if (newitem) {
                Items.push(newitem)
                $("#type").val("")
            }
        })

    </script>

</body>
```

Could you please advise me?

Comment: Where are you setting 'Items' like set localStorage.setItem('Items', VALUE)???

Comment: The use of variables not pointing to methods in the `onload` and `onunload` is very confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there we couple of issues with code. This snipped works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="LoadItems()" onunload="saveItems()">
    <div>
      <textarea id="inputBox" rows="2" cols="25"></textarea>
      <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Data in storage</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea id="showData" rows="2" cols="25"></textarea>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var Items = [];
      function LoadItems() {
        debugger;
        Items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Items"));
        if (!Items) Items = [];
        $("#showData").val(JSON.stringify(Items));
      }

      function saveItems() {
        var JSONItems = localStorage.setItem("Items", JSON.stringify(Items));
      }

      $("#submit").click(function() {
        var newitem = $("#inputBox").val();
        if (newitem) {
          Items.push(newitem);
          $("#inputBox").val("");
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is due to 2 different keys. You are using `TemasEFrases` as the key to set items, but while retrieving you are using `Items` as key. Try to use `Items` in both places.

I have created a working snippet on `JS Bin` assuming you are using jQuery for DOM manipulations.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <body>

    <textarea id="type" rows="2" cols="25"></textarea>

    <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>

    <p>Items:</p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <ul id="result"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var localstorageItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Items'));
  var items = localstorageItems || [];

  showItems();


  $('#submit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var newitem = $("#type").val()

    if (newitem) {
      items.push(newitem);
      $('#type').val('');

      localStorage.setItem('Items', JSON.stringify(items));
      showItems();
    }
  });

  function showItems () {
    if (items && items.length > 0) {
      var result = items.map(function (item) {
        return '<li>'+item+'</li>';
      });

      $('#result').html(result);
    }
  };
});
```

Here is the link to the working code https://jsbin.com/yoqoyoxiza/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, the original was TemasEFrases, but I changed everything to english for it to be easier to understand here. Thanks for spotting my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save it to local storage after each change:

```
 $("#submit").click(function() {
        var newitem = $("#type").val();
        if (newitem) {
            Items.push(newitem);
            $("#type").val("");
            // HERE:
            localStorage.setItem("Items", JSON.stringify(Items));
        }
 })
```